# Insert Array of strings to object

Tags: apex

I want to upsert some record, and the data stored in array of strings.. for example, the array below has 2 ID, which mean there`s only 2 data that will be updated.. how do I loop the array, so I can upsert the record with the right value.. ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the object's External Id that UUID that's prefixing the other data? How are the `AVAILABLE` and `OFFLINE` and so on values mapped to the object?

Comment: there`s an external_id on the custom object.. the external id = userId (first 36 char if you looking to that array).. and there`s custom field for each status (away,meal,meeting, and so on) on the custom object.. I want to insert the number value of each status (the number at the end of each array) to the status custom field..

Comment: my bad @crmprogdev I deleted the post without reading the notification 1st, sorry.. I appreciate your effort..

Comment: OK, so what have you tried to get this data mapped? Have you looked at String methods like `split()` and `left()` to break out the individual values? What kind of data structure might best suit a `Map`ping of an Id value to an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate strings like that :

```
 Map<string, CustomObject__c> customObjectByExternalId = new Map<string, CustomObject__c>();
for(string record: records)
{
     CustomObject__c customObject;
     List<string> data = record.split('_');
     if(customObjectByExternalId.containsKey(data[0]))
     {
        customObject = customObjectByExternalId.get(data[0]);
     }
     else
     {
        customObject = new CustomObject__c();
        customObject.ExternalId__c = data[0];
     }
     customObject.put(data[1]+'_sum__c', decimal.valueof(integer.valueof(data[2])/1000)); 
     customObjectByExternalId.put(data[0], customObject); 
}
upsert customObjectByExternalId.values();
```

Comment: Thanks Pragati, but the result only showed 1 Id (the second Id) .. USER_DEBUG PureCloud__c:{External_ID__c=ab24ddb8-f1ef-4cca-ae72-9f20f5975332, Available_Sum__c=204393, Away_Sum__c=0, Meeting_Sum__c=31, Training_Sum__c=7, Busy_Sum__c=1} ..

Comment: I updated the solution. Please check now.

Comment: @AriefGunawanTjiptorahardja above solution resolved your problem?

Comment: I tried this,
customObject.put(data[1]+'_sum__c', decimal.valueof(integer.valueof(data[2])/1000));

But this code below always giving me error Invalid field OFFLINE for PureCloud__c 
customObjectByExternalId.put(data[0], customObject);

There`s Offline_Sum__c field on the custom object..

Comment: make sure you updated the above code `customObject.put(data[1]+'_sum__c', decimal.valueof(integer.valueof(data[2])/1000));` in both places (`If`, '`else`)

Comment: it solved.. I convert the result to 'set' so there will be no duplicates before upserting the record.. thanks a lot Pragati..!

Comment: This might be more helpful to future readers if you can include some explanation of the logic here, since this is really a logic question.